# Stability of numerical schemes for difference equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

When estimating the solution to an ordinary differential equation, how can you tell if your difference scheme is stable? For example, consider the following scheme:
$$
u_{i+1} = 2u_{i} + hf(x_i,u_i), 
$$
where h is the size of a single step. Is this scheme stable?

I don't understand the definition of stability so I think an example would help me visualize what I am supposed to do. 
Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be helpful, both for yourself and for people trying to answer the question, to write down the precise definition of stability that you are working with.